# Server timed out in SimCity BuildIt

Tags: technical-issues, simcity-buildit

[image: An error message: "Server timed out. Please try again. (Error code: 60002.1001.999 - Player id: 0)]

I have installed the game for the very first time and still I can't make a single move to the game as when I open the game. It starts loading and while loading the error message suddenly pops up and then the game crashes down. I really need a fast fix for this.

Comment: Sometimes that happens to me and if my internet connection is working, I try restarting the app and it normally works.

Answer (score 2):

The game needs a live Internet connection to work. Are you connected to wireless or using cellular data?

If you are, there is a chance that the network you are on prevents game data communication. If not, that's probably your problem.

The message itself means that your game cannot talk to EA servers and is a network related problem. Once you solve that, your game should start working.